# node.js : redirecting urls from http to https working well with all my urls except one

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I have my cert and key and they are working well on my site and now I need to redirect my urls from the http to https urls. I have the http port 5000 and my https port are 443 so to redirecting from a http link like that: `http://localhost:5000/signin` to https link it will be like that `https://localhost/signin`

So I created this code and it worked without any problems on my all urls

```javascript
function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.secure) {
         var domain = "https://" + req.hostname;
         if (process.env["SSL_PORT"]) {
            domain = domain.replace(/:\d+$/, "");
            domain += ":" + process.env["SSL_PORT"];
         }
         //FYI this should work for local development as well
         return res.redirect(domain + req.url);
    }
    next();
}

app.use(requireHTTPS);
```

Except this url: `http://localhost:5000/`

It's supposed to redirect to something like that: `https://localhost/`

But it always gives me this result: `https://localhost:5000/`

And it gives me this error?

> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:5000. `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR`

So how do I redirect correctly?

the '/' path

```javascript
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if(req.user === undefined) {
        res.render('visitorsindex');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/themainpage');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should use a reverse proxy such as nginx or apache to handle  certificates and redirections

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is with this line:

```
domain = domain.replace(/:\d+$/, "");
```

This regular expression matches a colon plus 1 or more numeric digits at the end of the string. So, the following will work:

`http://localhost:5000` becomes `http://localhost`

But this will not:

`http://localhost:5000/` becomes `http://localhost:5000/`

Why? Because the port number is not at the end of the string; the "/" character is.

You can change the regular expression to the following:

```
domain = domain.replace(/:\d+[/]?$/, "");
```

This regex will optionally include the "/" at the end of the string.

But that's only going to match URLs without a path. You *could* extend the regex further to handle paths as well, but a better solution would be to use the node.js [URL module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) to parse the URL and change the port in a safe way.

Comment: nothing changed after replacing domain = domain.replace(/:\d+$/, ""); with domain = domain.replace(/:\d+[/]?$/, "");

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`domain.replace(/:\d+|\/$/, "");`

Comment: Can you explain how your solution works?  Regular expressions are hard enough to understand.  It would supplement this answer nicely for you to edit your answer to include an explanation of  your approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
    res.end();
}).listen(80);
```